# what to put in tensorflow's input to work

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Hello  I am trying an extremely simple project to just learn how things work in TensorFlow. I just gave 3 simple arrays and it doesn't find the relation between giving me an error. Why is that and how to overcome it? Here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

x = [[1,2,5,6],[12,5,1,7],[1,5,7,9]]
y = [[1],[4],[3]]

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x,y,epochs=20,batch_size=4)
```

error : 
ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays. You passed: x=[[1, 2, 5, 6], [12, 5, 1, 7], [1, 5, 7, 9]]

Comment: And what is your error?

Comment: Oh I forgot. Just added it.

Comment: FYI, given the number of labels (i.e. 3), you should either use `categorical_crossentropy` with one-hot-encoded `y`, or `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, we don't have native arrays. What you made with `x` and `y` are [lists](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). More precisely, lists of lists.

As the error message says, Tensorflow expects [numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) or list of arrays as input.

Add `import numpy` at top of your code and convert your `x` and `y` to numpy arrays before using them with your model.

```py
x = [[1,2,5,6],[12,5,1,7],[1,5,7,9]]
y = [[1],[4],[3]]

x = numpy.array(x)
y = numpy.array(y)
```

Comment: I think installing tensorflow will automatically also install numpy, but if an ImportError is raised, run `pip install numpy` from terminal.